# XNA 4.0 Collision Detection

Tags: collision-detection, xna-4.0

I have a 3D building, it is all one object, i.e. all one big mesh. I am using the camera as the player in my FPS. I know I have to make a bounding rectangle for the camera to represent a player but I don't know how to do that and attach it to the camera and then test if it collides with the mesh and not let it pass through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example explains about collision detection.  In order for you to use this, create the `BoundingSphere` around the cameras position.

[Riemers Collision Detection](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Collision_detection.php)